# Scale a (singly) Linked List by n Recursively

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, linked-list

I am trying to scale a linked list by a factor, n

Ex.

scale(3->5->7,2) should return 6->10->14

here's what I have so far: (assume node class is already defined and it has default data and next properties)
It is only returning the last element of the Node multiplied by n, i'm a bit stuck on what to do next.

```
def scale(head, n):
    if head is None:
        return None
    elif head.next is None:
        return(Node(head.data * n, None))
    else:
        return scale(head.next, n)
```

Comment: Are you trying to return a new list or modify the list in place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recursive step is incorrect, you're supposed to *build* a new list as you traverse it. This should work:

```
def scale(head, n):
    if head is None:
        return None
    else:
        return Node(head.data * n, scale(head.next, n))
```

Or even shorter, using the fact that a function implicitly returns `None`:

```
def scale(head, n):
    if head: return Node(head.data * n, scale(head.next, n))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty normal, because that's what you're telling your program to do. You can try with the iterative approach:

```
def scale(head, n):
    pointer = head

    while pointer.next: 
        pointer.data *= n
        pointer = pointer.next

    return head
```

Or if you insist on being recursive, you need to keep the head somewhere. To reuse your code, something like this will do:

```
def scale(head, n, first):
    if head is None:
        return None
    elif head.next is None:
        head = Node(head.data * n, None)
        return first
    else:
        return scale(head.next, n, first)
```

You will need to pass the head of your list as the third argument of your function while calling though.
Even smarter

```
def scale(head, n):
    if not head:
        return None
    else:
        return Node(head.data * n, scale(head.next, n))
```